# Need assistance to modify in the JS code

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have different URL's open while choosing options from drop1 & drop2.
example:

`http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis_country.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_OB` should open if i select BR as country

and

`http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_OB` should open if i select country as IN.

and

when there are no data for country like JP & OB or JP & AC, then the page should be blank without any contents..

How to modify the below code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxy').hide();
    $("#drop1, #drop2").on("change", function(){
        $('.boxy').hide();
        if ($('#drop1').val() !== "" && $('#drop2').val() !== "") {
            $("#content").show();
        $("#content").attr("src","http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_"+$('#drop2').val());
        }
    });
});
</script>

<select id="drop1">
    <option value="">---Select Country---</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2">
    <option value="">---Select PI---</option>
    <option value="OB">OB</option>
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="LQ">LQ</option>
</select>

<p>
    <iframe id="content" class="boxy" src="about:blank" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why does the code have to be modified at all? What's the problem with it?

Comment: Maybe I can help after you answered my questions.

Comment: What contents to be shown, should not be depedent on the selection of dropdown(s). This is what, you need to check in your .asp file.

Comment: @FelixKling: I have answered your questions.. the URL's in the question have been edited. the script code has a single URL, not multiple...

Comment: @ParkashKumar: the contents are yet to be added for certain countries like JP & AU... in the mean while i'm having these countries listed as per the requirement.

Comment: No matter, if the data doesn't exist you can show a message still. However, if you want to manage it through selection, you might need to add filter for those specific countries.

Comment: So, the only difference is that one URL contains `_country` and the other doesn't? What URL should be used for `US` and `DE`? How are `JP` and `AU` even relevant if they can't be selected? What have you tried so far to solve the issue on your own?

Comment: @FelixKling: for now IN, US & DE should go to inventory_analysis URL and BR should go to inventory_analysis_country URL... for JP, AU & so on.. it should not show any data..

Comment: @ParkashKumar: i dont want to complicate the code. I'm new to coding. it would be great if you can help with those filters

Comment: Then use a simple `if` statement: `if ($('#drop1').val() === 'BR') { /* use URL A */ } else { /* use URL B */ }`. *"or JP, AU & so on.. it should not show any data.."* It doesn't seem like JP or AU can be selected, so it's not possible to show or not show anything for them anyway.

Comment: *"I'm new to coding."* I recommend to read a tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide, http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can come up with something like following, if you want to add filters in your selection logic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxy').hide();
    $("#drop1, #drop2").on("change", function(){
        $('.boxy').hide();
        var drop1Value = $('#drop1').val();
        var drop2Value = $('#drop2').val();
        if (drop1Value !== "" && drop2Value !== "") {
            $("#content").show();
            if (drop1Value == 'BR') {
                $("#content").attr("src", "http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis_country.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_" + drop2Value);
            } else if (drop1Value == 'IN' || drop1Value == 'US' || drop1Value == 'DE'){
                $("#content").attr("src", "http://analytics.sial.com/rtp/inventory_analysis.asp?screen=Pricing_Inventory_" + drop2Value);
            } else {
                 $("#content").hide(); // hide iframe for no matches.
                 $(".message").show(); // show message, if you want
            }
        }
    });
});
```